# Iphone click event on position fixed

Tags: jquery, iphone, click, fixed

I have problem, i have element on position fixed, after click I enable modal:
**[Here is demo](https://jsfiddle.net/55v2Lvkp/5/)**

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click', '.modal, .modal-close', function(){
    $('.open').removeClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click', '.modal-content', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

On click circle i open modal with jquery, on android this works ok, but iPhone dont detect click event. How i can repair this?

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55v2Lvkp/9/)**.

Try to add `touch` also to the event :

```
$(document).on('click touch', '.open', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click touch', '.modal, .modal-close', function(){
    $('.open').removeClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click touch', '.modal-content', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

And try also to add the `cursor:pointer` to `open` element :

```
.open{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Or from the js code :

```
$('.open').css('cursor','pointer');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/55v2Lvkp/7/ now it works like focus, if I keep touch, check out demo

Comment: Ok, works on android, but on iphone this circle button dont work :/

Comment: I don't have iPhone but it works fine in the simulator.. not sure why that occur.